# Need help reading label text from dynamically created labels

Tags: c#, dynamic, time, label

I have a method name addDays that takes in the first day the month falls in and how many days the month has.  This method adds dynamic labels to a table 7x6 which would represent each day of the month of every week.  I also added events to each label so the person can click them.  The problem I am having is that I need to be able to read the labels that the person has click.  Lets say I run the application populate my calendar and I click on the first of the month, I then want to be able to capture the text of that label which would be 1.
Here is the code of my addDays method.

```
private void addDays(int day,int totaldays)
    {
            int reset = 0;
            Label newlabel;
            string label;
            int labelnum;
            Console.WriteLine("testoutputbeforebig forloop");
            //DayTableHold.Controls.Add(newlabel, 0, 6);
            int numday = 0;
            for (int coll = 0; coll <= 7; coll++)
            {

                    for (int row = 0; row <=6; row++)
                    {
                        if (numday < totaldays)
                        {
                            newlabel = new Label();
                            newlabel.AutoSize = true;


                            if (row==day &&coll==0)
                            {
                                labelnum = numday + 1;
                                label = labelnum.ToString();
                                newlabel.Text = label;
                                newlabel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(17, 0, 10, 0);
                                newlabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(days_Click);
                                DayTableHold.Controls.Add(newlabel, row, coll);

                                numday++;
                                reset = 1;
                                if (row == 6)
                                {
                                    coll = 1;

                                }
                                else coll = 0;
                                Console.WriteLine("testoutput1 " + numday + " " + label);

                            }
                            else if (reset == 1)
                            {
                                labelnum = numday + 1;
                                label = labelnum.ToString();
                                newlabel.Text = label;
                                newlabel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(17, 0, 10, 0);
                                newlabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(days_Click);
                                DayTableHold.Controls.Add(newlabel, row, coll);
                                numday++;
                                Console.WriteLine("test output2 " + numday + " " + label);
                            }



                        }



                }



        }

    }
```

This is my eventhandler for the labels click

```
    private void days_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here is were i want to capture the labels of the clicks.  
        count++;
        Console.WriteLine("day was click"+ count);


    } enter code here
```

Comment: you need to display the code where you define count++ also create an event delegate for example public delegate void EventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e); within that do something like this this.label.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.days_Click); you will have to change this to work correctly for your example.. also add the -= for the same event handler above

Answer (score 3):

You need to hook up to some event on the `Label` when you create it, so after your line:

```
newLabel = new Label();
```

you need to add a handler for the `Click` event:

```
newLabel.Click += new EventHandler(days_Click);
```

Then, inside your `Click` event handler, you can get the `Label` from the `sender` object:

```
Label selectedLabel = (Label)sender;
string labelText = selectedLabel.Text;
```

Comment: @ReyLopez Don't forget to upvote any helpful answers and accept the correct answer.